# Удалить всё, что между noindex и все ссылки с nofollow

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте.

Объясню на примере.

У нас есть контент:

```
<noindex>text</noindex> <a href="site.ru">Site</a> <noindex><a href="site1.ru">Site1</a></noindex> <a href="site2.ru" rel="nofollow">Site2</a>
```

Каким образом удалить всё, кроме `<a href="site.ru">Site</a>`?

Т.е. такая задача, что нужно удалить все, что находится внутри тегов `<noindex></noindex>` (текст, ссылки, картинки, видео - неважно, нужно всё удалять). Также нужно удалить все ссылки с nofollow. И нужно оставить только ссылки без nofollow и не в noindex.

Другой вариант, который я бы хотел получить больше - это сразу получение всех ссылок, которые не находятся внутри тегов `<noindex>` и у которых атрибут rel - не nofollow.

Наработки:

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<noindex>.*<\/noindex>)/Uis','', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/<a.*rel=("|\').*nofollow("|\').*>.*<\/a>/Ui', '', $content);
```

Думаю, можно было бы эти 2 строки как-нибудь объединить в одну, но как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через `|` эти два выражения спокойно объединяться.

```
<noindex>.*?<\/noindex>|<a[^>]+rel=\s*["'][^>]*nofollow["'][^>]*>.*?<\/a>
```